# parse android sdk proguard compilation errors

Tags: android, parse-platform, android-proguard

ok I know this issue has been answer many times, I have seen many post with all kind of recommendations, but no matter what mix I try the apk won't compile

this is my proguard-rules.pro files

```
# Keep source file names, line numbers, and Parse class/method names for easier debugging
-keepattributes SourceFile,LineNumberTable
-keepnames class com.parse.** { *; }
-keep class com.parse.** { *; }

# Required for Parse
-keepattributes *Annotation*
-keepattributes Signature
-dontwarn com.squareup.**
-dontwarn okio.**
-dontwarn com.parse.**
```

and my gradle file

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    signingConfigs {
        config {
            keyAlias 'xxxxxx'
            keyPassword 'xxxxxxx'
            storeFile file('/xxx/xxx/xxx/xxx/xxx/xxx.jks')
            storePassword 'xxxxxxx'
        }
    }
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "xx.xxx.xxxx"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 22
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0.0_beta1"
        renderscriptTargetApi 20
        renderscriptSupportModeEnabled true
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
            signingConfig signingConfigs.config
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile project(':viewpagerindicator')
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.1.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.1.1'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:8.4.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:8.4.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:8.4.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:23.1.1'
    compile 'com.bignerdranch.android:recyclerview-multiselect:+'
    debugCompile 'com.parse:parseinterceptors:0.0.1'
    compile 'com.parse:parsefacebookutils-v4-android:1.10.4@aar'
    compile('com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.8.0') {
        exclude module: 'bolts-android'
    }
    compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
    compile 'com.android.support:palette-v7:23.1.1'
    compile 'org.apmem.tools:layouts:1.10@aar'
    compile 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:2.0.0'
    compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.4'
    compile 'jp.wasabeef:picasso-transformations:1.3.1'
}
```

each time I try to build a release apk by changing to release variant in android studio, it give me errors that is not fouding anything about parse classes, like

```
Error:(4, 17) error: cannot find symbol class ParseClassName
Error:(5, 17) error: cannot find symbol class ParseGeoPoint
```

etc.
I don't know what else to try, any ideas?, thanks for you help

Comment: where is the main depend for parse ? ie  'com.parse:parse-android:1.10.3'

Comment: there isn't, according to the docs, in this class com.parse:parsefacebookutils-v4-android:1.10.4@aar they have the parse SDK embed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

so I finally discover the issue, in this line

```
debugCompile 'com.parse:parseinterceptors:0.0.1'
```

the parse:parseinterceptors are only used for dev, but for some reason without that class I can't have the Parse classes imported, don't know why, once I include the parse:parseinterceptors the rest of the classes are available, this answer my question, but if anybody knows the reason, that could help me and others in the future